# Trouble displaying markup inside a function MVC view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net, razor, recursion

Just trying to do a simple recursive function. I'm not sure if my logic is sound.

```
@listFamily(2)

@Functions
    Function listFamily(count As Integer) As Integer
        If (count > 0) Then

           Html.Raw(count)

           Return listFamily(count - 1)
       Else
           Return 0
      End If
    End Function
End Functions
```

I can see that count is getting 2 then 1 then 0, but `Html.Raw()` is not outputting anything

I'm just trying to output the value of `count` to the view inside the function. Instead I get 0.

Comment: So, `0` is being output to the view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `@listFamily(2)` is the only line which produces output in the view.  The `Html.Raw` inside your function only *[marks the text](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg480740%28v=vs.118%29.aspx)* so the MVC engine does not encode it.  It *does not* output anything.

Use a `[@helper][2]` instead since you want to output the results.

```
@Helper listFamily(count As Integer)
    @count

    If (count > 0) Then
        listFamily(count - 1)
    End If
End Helper
```